# How to ignore specific part of a text from a file and print the rest in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dictionary-comprehension

I am a beginner in python and trying to write a script to ignore the specific part from the text file and print the rest of the line

Input file:

```
ValueError: "invalid literal for int(12) with base", 10: This is an error in line 3
```

I am trying to replace the first colon with space and ignore the text after the second colon followed by a numerical value

output

```
ValueError  "invalid literal for int(12) with base"
```

I have an idea of using dictionaries but not sure how to implement it. Please help me if methods that are more efficient. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think you should be looking at string manipulation (searching, splitting, splicing); maybe regular expressions. Are there more lines that you can give as examples?

Comment: @sal Actually, Even though there are multiple colons in a line I am trying to ignore the text only if  a digit followed by a colon.

Comment: The number 10 is a significant part of the error message, it's saying the input is not a valid base 10 number (i.e. it doesn't consist solely of digits 0 through 9). Python can do other bases, too; for example, base 16 is hexadecimal (0-9 and A-F).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without Regular Expressions**:
Using the `split()` function, split it on the colons and join only the first two list elements. Then split it on the comma and return the first list element as result.

```
" ".join(('ValueError: "invalid literal for int(12) with base", 10: This is an error in line 3'.split(":"))[:-1])
```

Which would return:

```
ValueError "invalid literal for int(12) with base", 10
```

Then you can split it again and return the first element:

```
('ValueError "invalid literal for int(12) with base", 10'.split(","))[0]
```

Which would return:

```
ValueError "invalid literal for int(12) with base"
```

So to sum up:

```
error_string = 'ValueError: "invalid literal for int(12) with base", 10: This is an error in line 3'  
error_string = " ".join((error_string.split(":"))[:-1])   
error_string = (error_string.split(","))[0]
```

Or if you read it from a text file:

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as fi:
    lines = fi.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        error_string = line.rstrip()
        error_string = " ".join((error_string.split(":"))[:-1])
        error_string = (error_string.split(","))[0]
        # Do stuff here with the result
        print(error_string)
```

Comment: How do we write if the text is in some .txt file with multiples lines of same text

Comment: You could read the text file line for line and then process each line and store it in a list or do whatever you need to do with the result. ```with open("mytextfile.txt", "r") as fi:``` then ```lines = fi.readlines()``` then iterate over the lines ```for line in lines:``` then ```error_string = line.rstrip()```

Comment: it is showing me list has no attribute split. So what would it mean?

Comment: I added a portion to the answer which shows if you read it from a text file. Make sure you have the syntax exactly right because I tested it and it is working.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I got it now.

Comment: Great stuff! Please read this section when you have the time and familiarize yourself with the finer details on: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  I learned a lot from doing so and got better "hits" with my answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string substitution and regex operations:

```
import re
text = 'ValueError: "invalid literal for int(12) with base", 10: This is an error in line 3'
text = text.replace(":", " ", 1)
re.sub(r",\s+\d+:.*$", "", text)
```

The output is:

```
'ValueError  "invalid literal for int(12) with base"'
```

Comment: What's the reason for error say "object has no attribute replace" . The above code is working thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using regex `re.match` with `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = 'ValueError: "invalid literal for int(12) with base", 10: This is an error in line 3'
print(" ".join(re.match(r'([A-Za-z]+): (\".*?\")', s).groups()))
```

---

Or

```
m = re.match(r'([A-Za-z]+): (\".*?\")', s)
if m:
    print(" ".join(m.groups()))
```

**Output:**

```
ValueError "invalid literal for int(12) with base"
```

Comment: This would be the way to go. I would personally just match the "ValueError" (+ other errors, if needed), since of file has a line for example `Some text here, a:b, then more text, and "quoted" string`, then the there would be false match outputting `Some text here, a "quoted"`.